# "Close" and "Flag" don't work with Safari 12.1.1

Tags: support

It seems silly to ask, because there would already be a question here because it would affect very many people, but maybe I'm just too stupid:

If I click on "Close" or "Flag" on any stack exchange site with Safari 12.1.1, I see some animated dots next to the button for a very short time, then nothing happens. If I try and try again, a red message box tells me I have to wait three seconds to open the dialog again. But it never did open!

I allow pop-ups for this site (if the dialogs are pop-ups at all), have no blockers or extensions active. MacBook pro mid-2012, 10.14.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me! I found the reason. My StyleSheet was still set to [AdSubstract.css](https://code.google.com/archive/p/adsubtract/) since I-can't-remember-when, which seems to be incompatible with stack exchange. So somehow I had a blocker, but didn't know it, because it's not labelled a blocker, but a style sheet.

Comment: This will certainly help. We love to keep questions up. Feel free to select this as the answer unless a better answer comes along. Thank you for following up.